# How to set the dimensions for portrait images with the Paperclip gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I am using the paperclip gem to upload images,I want to upload both landscape and portrait images.Can any please help me how to set the dimension for both the images.

My code is:

```
has_attached_file :media,
  :styles => {:yplarge=>"440x300>"},
  :path => ":rails_root/public/system/:class/:id/:style/:basename.:extension", 
  :url  => "/system/buzz_pictures/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"

   validates_attachment_size :media, :less_than => 2.megabytes, 
     :message => "Please attach a smaller picture."
   validates_attachment_content_type :media, 
     :content_type=>['image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif']
```

This code is working for landscape images but not for portrait.

Comment: but what do you want to do with portrait ones? crop them to "300x440>"?

Comment: i want to upload both the landscape and portrait at a time.

Comment: you mean you waant to rotate the pic and save it too as another style?

Answer (score 0):

Just add another style:

```
:styles => {
  :yplarge=>"440x300>",
  :portrait=>"300X440>"
}
```

Change the values as needed. Note that if the image is smaller than the given dimensions then it won't resize it. To change that behavior replace the the `>` with `#`. This will force the image to be resized to the specified dimensions.

Refer to the Paperclip documentation for using your different styles:

https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Thumbnail-Generation

Answer (score 0):

the solution below will save 2 styles, portrait rotated by 90 if original in landscape, and vice versa.

```
has_attached_file :media,
  :styles => {:landscape => Proc.new { |a| { :geometry => "440x300>", :rotation => 90 unless a.landscape? } }, 
              :portrait => Proc.new { |a| { :geometry => "300x440>", :rotation => 90 if a.landscape? } } }
  :path => ":rails_root/public/system/:class/:id/:style/:basename.:extension", 
  :url  => "/system/buzz_pictures/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
  :processors => [:rotator]

def landscape?
  Paperclip::Geometry.from_file(to_file(:original)).horizontal?
end

module Paperclip
  class Rotator < Thumbnail
    def transformation_command
      if rotate_command
        super + rotate_command
      else
        super
      end
    end

    def rotate_command
      if @options[:rotation]
        " -rotate #{ @options[:rotation] }"
      end
    end
  end
end
```